# Error when create simple people directory in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-import

I've follow this tutorial to sync data from Active Directory to SP 2013 : http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/introduction-of-sharepoint-2013-active-directory-import/
And I've got this connection:
[image]

Then I've follow this tutorial to create simple people directory, but I've got 0 result from search. It should be alot of resuft, but I don't see it. Is it because my Sharepoint 2013 not sync with Active Directory or is there something went wrong?[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be able to search for people, there are some additional steps you must take which include to configure My Sites, have a working managed metadata service and then crawl the users properties.

Follow the steps from Microsoft to set it up in your environment correctly.

Doing an AD import is simply not enough.

[Deploy people search in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: there are alot of config @@. So do you know any other ways to create a People Directory?

Comment: Well, to be honest i think this is the best way to get relevant data, and keep the updates automatically and directly from the AD. If you got data you could just create a custom list, but that would be a lot of work to administrate it.